# PHP JSON decode without foreach

Tags: php, json, decode

how can I get the "avatarmedium" from i json without a foreach Loop?
Thats my current Code:

```
   $json = '{
    "response": {
        "players": [
            {
                "steamid": "76561198019025166",
                "avatarmedium": "https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/steamcommunity/public/images/avatars/d3/d3ca76e0f1e8d071e826bc3baeebd0e7215e50e2_medium.jpg"

            }
        ]

    }
}';

$result = json_decode ($json);
echo $json->response[0]->players->profileurl;
```

Thank you
with best regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
       $json = '{
    "response": {
        "players": [
            {
                "steamid": "76561198019025166",
                "avatarmedium": "https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/steamcommunity/public/images/avatars/d3/d3ca76e0f1e8d071e826bc3baeebd0e7215e50e2_medium.jpg"

            }
        ]

    } }';

$result = json_decode ($json); 
echo $result->response->players[0]->avatarmedium;
```